# Is Bob the Pirate an original character?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets, valerian-and-laureline

In the movie adaptation of *Valerian and Laureline*, Bob the Pirate is a very lively and eye catching character.

Is he a Besson creation, or can he be found in the original comics material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bob the Pirate is a creation of Luc Besson. But there is a somewhat similar character in the comic book that most likely inspired this character.

The character in the comic book arrives in a boat right after Laureline has used the caught jelly fish (there is no captain in the mini sub in the comic), he is a former space farer that now is poor, and has many mechanical implants, he sells info about another species that might help in her quest to find Valerian.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this character have a name I could google?